# Firebase (Android) - Loading filtered data into custom ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase

Can someone please advice me on this issue:
I am trying to load some filtered data from Firebase DB onCreate and populate a custom array with data.

After doing some debugging I can tell that the data is loaded from DB but my custom array is not getting populated.

Please have a look at my code below.

Even though my loadAllBooks() method is populating the array, it gets completed too late and the line:

```
//3) Create the adapter 
BooksAdapter  adapter = new BooksAdapter  (this, booksList);
```

is executed before loadAllBooks() is completed which results in an empty list...
It's as if i need some sort of onComple for the addChildEventListener...

Please Help, if more information is needed let me know, thank you:

```
ArrayList<BookItem> booksList;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //1) empty books list
    booksList = new ArrayList<BookItem>();

    //2) load all books from firebase DB - into booksList array
    loadAllBooks();

    //3) Create the adapter 
    BooksAdapter  adapter = new BooksAdapter  (this, booksList);

    //4) Attach the adapter to a ListView
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBooks);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void loadAllBooks() {
    Firebase ref = new Firebase(".......firebaseio.com/books");
    Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("bookType").equalTo("drama");
    queryRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
}

ChildEventListener childEventListener  = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded (DataSnapshot bookNode, String previousChild){
        BookItem bookItemModel = bookNode.getValue(BookItem.class);
        booksList.add(bookItemModel);
    }

    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot) {}

    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild){}

    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: *...it gets completed too late and the line*  - this doesn't matter if that listener actually gets called. So make sure it gets called(you could simply add a log statement) and also call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter after updating the list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code you posted will populate `booksList` if it's attached to a location that contains the relevant data and that the user can read from. But I don't know how `booksList` is used in your `BooksAdapter` and whether it invokes `notifyDataSetChanged()` correctly. My guess is that you're better off using [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). I recommend starting with the associated [codelab](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/codelabs/chat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `addChildEventListener()` Firebase *starts loading* the data from the remote location *asynchronously*. This means that the code after it executes straight away and you pass an empty list to the adapter. Later, when the initial data has synchronized from Firebase, it is added to the list. But by that time you've already created the adapter.

You can most easily see the flow, by adding a few log statements:

```
System.out.println("Start loading/synchronizing books");
loadAllBooks();

System.out.println("Creating adapter");
BooksAdapter  adapter = new BooksAdapter  (this, booksList);

public void onChildAdded (DataSnapshot bookNode, String previousChild){
    System.out.println("Adding book to list");
    BookItem bookItemModel = bookNode.getValue(BookItem.class);
    booksList.add(bookItemModel);
}
```

These will print in this order:

> Start loading/synchronizing books
>
> Creating adapter
>
> Adding book to list
>
> Adding book to list
>
> Adding book to list
>
> ...

Likely this is not the order that you expected. Welcome to asynchronous loading 101, it makes the modern web tic and makes developers lose their mind when they first encounter it. :-)

Most likely all that is required is that you call [`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) from `onChildAdded()`. This informs Android that the data in the adapter has changed and that it should repaint the associated view(s).

```
public void onChildAdded (DataSnapshot bookNode, String previousChild){
    BookItem bookItemModel = bookNode.getValue(BookItem.class);
    booksList.add(bookItemModel);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Note that I can't be sure if this will work, because you didn't include the code for `BooksAdapter` in your question.

Comment: Thanks Frank, this does work!!! Great/detailed explanation as well (as usual from your answers). Thanks.

Comment: " lose their mind when they first encounter it." 

you can say that again.